# Access global this in Arrow function

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

I have two functions. One is normal function and one is arrow function inside an object.
Inside the arrow function I want to access the inner Name and global name.

```js
const name = "globalname";
const obj = {
  name: 'john G',
  regularFunction: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('from Regular Function ', this.name)
    }, 100);
  },
  arrowFunction: () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('from Arrow Function: ' + this.name) //here want to access the global name and object level name variable.
    }, 200)
  }
}

obj.regularFunction();
obj.arrowFunction();
```

Comment: Use `name`, not `this.name`, to access the global variable.